# How to configure Apache to work with Django

Tags: django, apache

I've followed the [instructions on Django website](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/) for configuring Apache  with my Django app on a CentOS 7 server.   This included building mod_wsgi from sources to work with the installed python3.4.

Apache restarts without errors but when I hit my app with the URL
http://example.com/myapp/

I get a 503 error like:

```
Service Temporarily Unavailable

The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to    maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later.

Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS) Server at example.com Port 80
```

I'm not sure how I troubleshoot what's wrong here.  Can anyone help?

Details of the config:

My django app lives at /mnt/net/django/myapp

I've added the file wsgi.conf to my apache conf.d directory and it looks like this:

```
#LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so
# use python34 pip installes mod_wsgi
LoadModule wsgi_module "/usr/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi-py34.cpython-34m.so"
    #WSGIPythonHome "/usr"

Alias /robots.txt /mnt/net/django/myapp/static/robots.txt
Alias /favicon.ico /mnt/net/django/myapp/static/favicon.ico
Alias /media /mnt/net/django/myapp/media/
Alias /static/ /mnt/net/django/myapp/static/

<Directory /mnt/net/django/myapp/static>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Directory>

<Directory /mnt/net/django/myapp/media>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Directory>


# Allows URLs like example.com/myapp to forward to django 
WSGIScriptAlias /myapp /mnt/net/django/myapp/myappsite/wsgi.py process-group=example.com


# Use the virtual env for the myapp site
#WSGIPythonHome /mnt/net/django/myapp/env-myapp-py3-4
# Need to use WSGIDaemon
WSGIDaemonProcess example.com python-home=/mnt/net/django/myapp/env-myapp-py3-4 python-path=/mnt/net/django/myapp
#WSGIPythonPath /mnt/net/django/myapp

<Directory /mnt/net/django/myapp/myappsite>
<Files wsgi.py>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Files>
</Directory>
```

Comment: Did you try reading the documentation, which has extremely detailed instructions for deploying with Apache? Note that proxying to the development server is very definitely *not* the way to do it: the development server is just that, for development only.

Comment: How did you install mod_wsgi, with a yum install? mod_wsgi has to be compiled against the same version of Python you develop Django with.

Comment: Yes.  I did a yum install.  Since I had to install python 3.5 by building it I think I must have to build mod_wsgi too.  thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[How to use Django with Apache and mod_wsgi](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/) -- follow this: I have done it myself many times, it is very straight forward.

*Tip: Create a document and record everything you do whilst setting this up, this way if it doesn't work then you can retrace your steps, but if it does work... Great, you have your very own guide to setting up an Apache server for Django.*

Comment: I've followed the instructions at [How to use Django with Apache and mod_wsgi](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/) very faithfully (including a mod_wsgi built for the python3.4 on my server) and when I try to access my django site I get a 503 error.  EDIT ABOVE to the original question to reflect what I've done.

Answer (score 0):

Solved my problem (mostly)
The problem is that mod_wsgi with a daemon process tries to write a socket file into the apache logs directory and permissions are denied.

Solution is to tell apache another place to write the socket like this:

```
WSGISocketPrefix /var/run/wsgi
```